# Any good Haar Cascades for detecting hands?

Tags: image-processing, haar-classifier

I am looking for a haar cascade that can detect hands. I would rather not have to train my own as I am on a regular laptop (I think it would take too long without a powerful computer). Also, I don't know where I would get the images from, and I've never done it before so I have a feeling I would do it wrong and waste a week training a haar cascade that doesn't work.

I know there are similar questions that have been asked already, but they all are from several years ago, so I am wondering if anything new has been created.